# How the --reload-delay and --reload-debounce commands work? (Browsersync)

Tags: node.js, npm, browser-sync

How should I use Browsersync's `--reload-delay` and `--reload-debounce` options?

I tried using them in the command like this:

```
browser-sync start --server --files "* .css, * .html, * .js" --reload-delay "100ms"
```

However, nothing worked.

Comment: Try `--reload-delay 100` i.e specify  the ms value as a number and not a string.

Comment: Tried it unfortunately does not work ...
The browser still restarts after saving the file after about 1.8 seconds